# How to format Instagram date in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter, instagram

i have a little problem, when i get the answer from Instragm, i get this date format:

```
            "created_time" = 1361964707;
```

what the hell does this means?? and specially how can i format this with the NSdataFormatter?

I am looking for a way to format a date like this.

```
"created_time": "Wed Dec 01 17:08:03 +0000 2010"
```

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Computers typically calculate dates as the number of seconds since some arbitrary point in time (the "epoch date".) You can use floating point numbers for sub-second accuracy.

The UNIX epoch date is midnight, January 1970 in UTC. (AKA Greenwich mean time.)

The epoch date for Mac OS and iOS is midnight on Jan first, 2001.

The Unix Epoch date is a fairly common standard for date exchange on the internet. My bet is that is a Unix Epoch date.

NSDate has methods to convert between these "number of seconds" dates and NSDate objects:

```
+[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:]      //Unix Epoch to NSDate
+[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:] //Mac * iOS Epoch to NSDate

-[NSDate timeIntervalSince1970]  //Unix epoch value for an NSDate
-[NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]  //Mac & iOS epoch value for an NSDate
```

So, you should be able to take that date and use timeIntervalSince1970 to convert it to an NSDate. Remember that the date you get back will be in Greenwich mean time, and you will need to convert it to your local time zone.

This code will display that date as an NSDate in UTC:

```
  NSTimeInterval interval = 1361964707.0;
  NSDate *aDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970: interval];
  NSLog(@"Date = %@", aDate);
```

I get a result of

> Date = 2013-02-27 11:31:47 +0000

Given that that is a date in 2013, I'm betting it's correct.

Answer (score 5):

It's a unix timestamp (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

You convert it to NSDate with `[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:];`  once that's done, you can use NSDateFormatter on it.

Comment: I guess our posts "crossed in the mail."